# Remove rows from Pandas dataframe where values appears more than once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
ID  EM_results  pa_id_1850
 0           0           1 
 1           1           1 
 2           0           1 
 3           0           2 
 4           0           2 
 5           1           3 
 6           1           3 
 7           0           3
```

I want to remove all the rows where EM_results is occurring as 1 more than once per pa_id_1850 index. In this case:

```
ID  EM_results  pa_id_1850
 0           0           1 
 1           1           1 
 2           0           1 
 3           0           2 
 4           0           2
```

I have tried something like:

```
grouped = df.groupby('pa_id_1850')    
grouped.filter(lambda x: (x['EM_results'] == 1) <= 1)
```

But I can't quite get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is close: `filter` needs to return a scalar, not a Series. One way to achieve this is to filter on the sum of `EM_results` values in each group, assuming these values are only ever 0 or 1:

```
grouped = df.groupby('pa_id_1850')    
grouped.filter(lambda x: (x['EM_results'].sum()) <= 1)

# Output:

   ID  EM_results  pa_id_1850
0   0           0           1
1   1           1           1
2   2           0           1
3   3           0           2
4   4           0           2
```

Comment: Additionally, I think you could use `lambda x: (x['EM_results'] == 1).sum() <= 1` to only select groups where 1 appears 1 or 0 times. Useful if `"EM_results"` has more values.

Comment: This did the job - much appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Compute a boolean mask with the help of `transform`, then apply it to the dataframe.

```
>>> mask = df.groupby('pa_id_1850')['EM_results'].transform('sum').le(1)
>>> df = df[mask]
>>> df
   ID  EM_results  pa_id_1850
0   0           0           1
1   1           1           1
2   2           0           1
3   3           0           2
4   4           0           2
```